# Eagle printed PCB scale problem

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, scaling

I have made a layout using eagle then save it as PDF to print a test paper before routing.
[image: exporting layout to PDF on eagle]
I didn't design any package its all eagle's packages.
I exported PDF as shown on the image but the problem is :
the atmega16 and l293d and even ne555 packages are all scaled down on the printed paper !
as you can see on the other image i put the real component aligned with the printed paper
[image: Real component doesn't match eagle printed layout test paper] but they didn't match ?!

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: Did you remember to select 100% scaling in your printer driver? This means deselecting "scale to fit page" or whatever it might be called for your particular printer.

Comment: I'd guess the same. Another hint: You are exporting to DIN A4 paper format. If that does not match your paper, the printer itself may try to scale the A4 document to fit on your paper. I'm not sure if Adobe reader can 'measure' today, but other PDF tools can. You can use them to check if EAGLE scaled the picture, or it's the printer / printing process. However, EAGLE is quite exact, and it's most probable a problem of printer / printer settings.

Comment: What did you mean dave with " printer driver " the adobe reader or something else ?

Comment: sweber, i exported the pdf as A4 and the printer accept A4

Comment: When you go to print the PDF from Adobe Reader check the "Printer Properties" or similar option in the print dialog. In there will be something along the lines of "Shrink page to fit" turned on.  Turn it off, or change it to something along the lines of "Crop page to fit" or however it is worded on your OS / Driver / Software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to produce scale-accurate print you need to print the drawing from Eagle. For example, in board editor go to the top menu and select File->Print.In the window that follows pick your options. Scale factor will be one by default. You can also print to PDF from there but then you'd have to be careful with PDF renderer as they all tend to rescale in order to fit the image to the page.

I always check my footprints using the above method and it proved to be quite accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to All replies i found that printing shop was printing it wrongly they print PDF from adobe x ver. 10 without correcting the print setting 
adobe has option under **print** -> **size option**  -> check **Actual size**
[image: Adobe printing adjustment]

this has done the job

[image: real part match printed pads]

Thanks All.